# Multiple attributes in class Python

Tags: python, oop

```
class Dog(object):
    species = "mammal"
    def __init__(self, breed, name, color):
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name

sam = Dog(breed="lab", name="maorian", color="white")
```

However, I am unable to use the "color" attribute.Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set it in the initializer. Add `self.color = color` after the `self.name = name` line.

Comment: Thanks. But if I have say 100 attributes, doesnt this get too messy?

Comment: @Nirupbelongokar if you have a hundred attributes, that's a code smell: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/large-class